# Return one array of data in sub-document of Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nested, mongodb-query

I'm using Nodejs with Mongoose package. 
Given I've something like this:-

```
let people = [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "pets": [
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "Tom",
                "category": "cat" 
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "name": "Jerry",
                "category": "mouse" 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get only the data of `Jerry` in `pets array` using it's `_id` *(result shown below)*

```
{
     "_id": 2,
     "name": "Jerry",
     "category": "mouse" 
}
```

Can I get it without needing to specify the `_id` of `person 1` when using `$elemMatch`? Right now I code like this:-

```
const pet = People.find(
    { "_id": "1"}, // specifying 'person 1 _id' first
    { pets: { $elemMatch: { _id: 2 } } } // using 'elemMatch' to get 'pet' with '_id' of '2' 
)
```

And it gave me what I want like I've shown you above. But **is there any other way** I can do this **without needing to specify** the `_id` of it's parent first (in this case, the `_id` of the `people array`)

Comment: You can use the [positional $ projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html). But, you still need to specify the array field _being limited_ - **must** appear in the query filter. This is same as using the `$elemMatch` - just that `$elemMatch` projection is useful when projecting using multiple fields.

Comment: You're specifying `{ "_id": "1"}` in `filter` just to make sure to get only one doc in response & in projection you're using `$elemMatch` to match respective object in `pets` array, So if you remove `{ "_id": "1"}` from filter then you'd get multiple docs(all docs which have atleast one object with `"_id": 2` in pets array) in o/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming nested array's `_id`'s are unique you can filter by nested array elements directly:

```
const pet = People.find(
    { "pets._id": 2 },
    { pets: { $elemMatch: { _id: 2 } } }
)
```